# Changes to an SDF database file are never saved

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

Whenever I do restart the application, changes to a DataTable are never saved in the SDF database file.

Example :

```
_table.Clear();
_adapter.Update(_table);
```

Or

```
_table.Clear();
_adapter.Update(_dataSet);
```

I also tried the following but without success :

[Local Data Cache Sync does not save client changes to sdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769491/local-data-cache-sync-does-not-save-client-changes-to-sdf-file)

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, without knowing what `_table` is, any reason why you are clearing it before saving it?

Comment: I am making some tests, this is why. And _table is the table I have added rows to.

Comment: In that case nothing is updating because you have flushed your table of any rows before calling update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you attempting to delete all rows from the database?

`DataTable.Clear` clears all the rows from the table:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clear.aspx

It doesn't mark them for deletion, which is what you would need to do to remove them on an update:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/feh3ed13(v=vs.80).aspx